# Charles proxy issue with my Android 13 in some apps

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

I've been using Charles Proxy in my Android 13 for a while. I installed the certificate and It worked fine so far tracking the requests.

My problem is when I'm not using Charles. As soon as I remove the proxy from my wifi settings in Android and close Charles, some apps doesn't seem to work. Apps like gmail, chrome, and others works fine, but on other apps it just won't work.

As soon as I connect the proxy and init charles again, this apps works fine. I don't know why is this happening and why only in some apps.

I've tried to remove all the certificates in my Android, the proxy config and restarting. Even removing the IP of my Android in the registered IP in Charles but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you share which apps cause problems?

Comment: Twitter doesn't load images. Wallapop and TooGoodToGo can't even open.

Comment: Do the apps start working again once you clear the app data? (Admittedly poking in the mist here.)

Comment: Nope, not even reinstalling them works.